# Что будет если подключившись к серверу по SSH закрыть терминал без команды exit?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Что будет если подключившись к серверу по SSH закрыть терминал без команды exit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

выполняющийся процесс получит сигнал [hup](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP).

что будет дальше — целиком и полностью зависит от того, что разработчики вложили в программу. по умолчанию она должна завершиться.

---

скрипт для проверки:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'touch hupped; exit' hup

echo $$

while :; do sleep 1; echo -n .; done
```

сначала он выводит номер своего процесса, а затем раз в секунду выдаёт в *stdout* символ «точка». при получении сигнала *hup* создаёт в текущем каталоге файл `hupped` и завершает работу.

Answer (score 9):

Если терминал завершен корректно, то посылает команду закрыть соединение ssh, дальше сигнал hup всем процессам. Если процесс терминала убить, то операционная система посылает tcp-fin пакет, возникает исключение на сервере, дальше hup. Если соединение было разорванной некорректно , например отключилась сеть, то fin не дойдёт и процесс будет выполняться какое-то время (около получаса обычно) пока соединение не разорвется по таймауту сервером. Дальше как и в других случаях hup.

Comment: Разорвать соединение по тайм-ауту так, чтобы получился hup, может только сервер, не роутер.

Comment: проверил, не рвет.

Answer (score 4):

По закрытию контролирующего терминала *bash получает SIGHUP и выходит*, [в интерактивном случае] пересылая сигнал всем процессам из списка её задач (job). Остановленные задачи получают также SIGCONT. Из [документации bash по сигналам](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html) (что соответствует ожидаемому поведению групп процессов, создаваемых с помощью [`setpgid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html)) :

> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP. Before exiting, an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or stopped. Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive the SIGHUP. To prevent the shell from sending the SIGHUP signal to a particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin (see Job 
>   Control Builtins) or marked to not receive SIGHUP using disown -h.

`nohup` позволяет игнорировать SIGHUP сигнал, `disown` команда позволяет исключить задачу из этого списка. [systemd 230 версия](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/0d18f808a453dff4b47a4929dac6f58271a886f9/NEWS#L1190-L1196) изменяет поведение по умолчанию при завершении пользовательской сессии.

*ssh процесс на клиенте получает SIGHUP*. ssh при получении сигнала восстанавливает stdin, если необходимо, пересылает сигнал proxy-команде, если есть и [выходит](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/6a9481258a77b0b54b2a313d1761c87360c5f1f5/clientloop.c#L2306-L2316). В сторону, обычно, при нормальном выходе bash (exit, <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>), SIGHUP не будет послан задачам, так как `huponexit` опция выключена по умолчанию. [In which cases is SIGHUP not sent to a job when you log out?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84737/1321)

При этом на сервере могут не сразу узнать, что ssh клиент умер. [Does getting disconnected from an SSH session kill your programs?](https://serverfault.com/q/463366/3933) Когда sshd на сервере заметит что соединение мертво, это *приводит к посылке SIGHUP сигнала уже на сервере* и повторяется поведение из цитаты выше.

Comment: спасибо, но очень сложно

Comment: @Hipster: вам уже дали упрощённые ответы. Даже мой ответ является упрощением того, что вы можете фактически встретить (он описывает ситуацию: вы закрыли GNOME terminal окошко, в котором у вас bash был запущен, в котором ssh интерактивно был запущен, который на той стороне зашёл в систему также в bash). К примеру, наличие терминала локально, не говорит, что он обязан быть выделен удалённо также. Или поведение может разниться в зависимости от версии ПО. Все эти детали начинают иметь значение, когда вы хотите узнать, «а почему вот этот процесс умер/не умер при закрытии терминала.»