# Переподключение к VM во время компиляции. Статус компиляции

Tags: linux, ssh

Бывает такое, что подключаешься к удаленной Linux VM через *ssh*. Начинаешь компилировать библиотеку, например OpenCV, и происходит обрыв соединения. После переподключения к VM ты уже не видишь на каком этапе происходит компиляция, сколько процентов завершено, вылезла ли ошибка, завершилось ли? Можно как-то это отследить?

Comment: tmux, screen и другие похожие штуки.

Comment: *ты уже не видишь* — [и никто не видит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723456/178576)