# Не умирает процесс при завршении сесии

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, shell

При завершении сессии оболочка посылает всем порожденным ею процессам сигнал HUP, по которому некоторые из порожденных ею процессов могут завершиться, что не всегда желательно. Но при выходе из терминала запущенный мною в фоне процесс продолжает работать. Если посмотреть ps то изменился только его ppid. Однако если прописать kill -HUP  он вырубается. Почему он не вырубается при выходе из терминала? Сигнал ведь одинаковый.

P.S: Запускал node (node app.js &),
OS: Debian 9

Comment: связанный вопрос [Что будет если подключившись к серверу по SSH закрыть терминал без команды exit?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723456/23044)

Comment: попробуйте по шагам детально описать как воспроизвести ошибку. Получается воспроизвести если `/bin/sleep 321` вместо node использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему он не вырубается при выходе из терминала?

Потому, что при запуске в фоне процесс ОТСОЕДИНЯЕТСЯ от сессии текущего терминала. И когда закрывается сессия, SYGHUB ему просто не посылается.

Comment: Но если посмотреть jobs терминала, то там будет данный процесс. И родителем останется bash, следовательно процесс не отвязался от терминала

Comment: > родителем останется bash

Родитель - это тот, кто ПОРОДИЛ. Так как это уже произошло в прошлом, то отменить это невозможно. Но,каждый процесс входит в *сессию*, а каждая сессия может быть привязана к *терминалу*. При переходе в фон процесс должен:
- Отвязаться от сессии, связанной с текущей консолью
- Созать сессию, не привязанную ни чему
- Войти в эту сессию.

Comment: Спасибо большое!